# How do I remove the VLAN ID from my NIC (Netadapter)

Tags: windows, powershell, vlan, nic, network-teaming

So I am running a Windows 2019 datacenter server core running hyper-v which has a
Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet BCM5720 NIC with 2 access ports. The Server is patched into a VLAN.

So earlier on I assigned a VLAN ID to the netadapter using powershell:

```
set-netadapter -name nic1 -vlanid 240
```

Later on I figured it would be a good idea to enable Switch Embbedded Teaming for the virtual switch:

[Switch Embedded Teaming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/rdma-and-switch-embedded-teaming)

Reading on the documention I read that if you use a virtual switch with teaming you should not put a vlanID on the NIC:
*"2)    Anytime you have NIC Teaming enabled, you must not set VLAN filters on the NICs using the NICs advanced properties settings. Let the teaming software or the Hyper-V switch (if present) do the filtering."*

So finally my question. I am trying to remove the VLAN ID is set on the NIC, but I can't seem to find an easy way to this. The set-netadapter cmdlet doesn't seem to do it.

Anybody any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: A quick and dirty way, erase nic1 and hit f5 to have it redetected and reinstalled ?

Comment: i'll give it a shot, but I just realized it might be easy as setting the VLAN ID to 0

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24404/vlan-0-1-and-4095-are-reserved-what-are-they-reserved-for and https://altospheric.com/nutanix-ce/powershell-script-to-set-or-remove-vlan-id-for-nutanix-microsoft-hyper-v-clusters/ support your theory that setting it to zero will have the effect you want.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple:

You need to write this command in PowerShell:

```
Set-NetAdapter -Name nic1 -VlanID 0
```

where `nic1` is the name of your adapter.

You can check VLAN on your interfaces this command in PowerShell:

```
Get-NetAdapter | select interfacealias,vlanid
```